# How do you replace set_tight_layout with set_layout_engine?

Tags: python, matplotlib, deprecation-warning

When I call `fig.set_tight_layout(True)` on a Matplotlib figure, I receive this deprecation warning:

```
The set_tight_layout function will be deprecated in a future version. Use set_layout_engine instead.
```

How do I call `set_layout_engine` so as to match the current behavior as closely as possible?

```
Environment: 

OS: Mac
Python: 3.10.6
matplotlib: 3.7.2
```

Comment: [fig.set_layout_engine('tight')](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_layout_engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_layout_engine

```
fig.set_layout_engine("tight")
```